# Railties cannot load such file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

First, you should know upfront I am a newb to rails so I apologize if this is a dumb mistake but I've been racking my brain on it and thought I'd ask for some help.

I am currently unable to start my local rails server all of the sudden. Not sure what I've done to cause this as I was able to start it earlier today just fine. Only thing I've done in between it working and not was trying to figure out how to push the app to Heroku.

When running `rails s` while in root of the app I get this error:

```
/Users/jonathanmacdonald/code/lrbp/config/application.rb:6:in `require':     cannot load such file -- active_job/railtie (LoadError)
    from /Users/jonathanmacdonald/code/lrbp/config/application.rb:6:in     `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-    4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-    4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-    4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-    4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-    4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-    4.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jonathanmacdonald/code/lrbp/bin/rails:10:in `require'
    from /Users/jonathanmacdonald/code/lrbp/bin/rails:10:in `<top     (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-    1.6.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-    1.6.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-    1.6.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-    1.6.2/lib/spring/client.rb:28:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-1.6.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top     (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-    1.6.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/spring-    1.6.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in     `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in     `require'
    from /Users/jonathanmacdonald/code/lrbp/bin/spring:13:in `<top     (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `load'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

group :production do
  gem 'rails', '4.2.3'
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'better_errors'
end
```

**config/application.rb**

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require "rails"
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Lrbp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those     specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record     auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names.     Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from     config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.    {rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # Do not swallow errors in after_commit/after_rollback callbacks.
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
  end
end
```

### Things I've tried after research

- `bundle exec rails server` ->> Still won't start and produces the exact same error
- Temporarily `mv Gemfile.lock ..` so that I could regenerate it with `bundle install` ->> No change. Same error.
- `gem pristine --all` ->> No change. Same error.
- `gem uninstall rails` and then afterwards `gem install rails` ->> No change. Same error.

### Setup

- OS X 10.11.2
- Rails 4.2.3
- Ruby 2.0.0

What can I look for or try? Any help is appreciated. Let me know if you need any more information in order to help.

Comment: paste the code from the stack trace `config/application.rb:6`

Comment: can you try `bundle exec rails s`?

Comment: @Haymaker87 I've revised the code above with ```config/application.rb:6``` added.

Comment: @RajarshiDas Is there a difference in running ```bundle exec rails s``` vs running ```bundle exec rails server```? I've done this already and it didn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: no no difference but `require "active_job/railtie"` it is in your application.rb but did you use active_job gem? please remove ``require "active_job/railtie"``

Answer (score 0):

Your `application.rb` will look like

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

module Lrbp
  class Application < Rails::Application
```

you do not require to each rails module separately like

```
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
```

you can use.

```
  require 'rails/all'
```

it will do something like this

```
%w(
  active_record
  action_controller
  action_view
  action_mailer
  rails/test_unit
  sprockets
).each do |framework|
  begin
    require "#{framework}/railtie"
  rescue LoadError
  end
end
```

and Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

  gem 'rails', '4.2.3'
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'better_errors'
end
```

Then you should do

```
bundle install & bundle exec rails s
```

Comment: ```/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing': undefined method `active_record' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007fbeb4ebe590> (NoMethodError)```

Comment: What is odd is that looking back at this file's history on github, it hasn't changed meaning that the way I posted it above is the way it was when I could run ```rails s``` successfully. I could be very wrong, but it doesn't make sense to me that the issue is with this file (although the stack trace says otherwise).

Comment: your gemfile also wrong it point rails for production not for development